# How do I ensure that only my Node.js app in app engine can connect to my CloudSQL database?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-sql

I am very new to backend development and to Google Cloud and I am exploring building a web app with a frontend built with React that communicates with an API server (Node Express) hosted on App Engine connected to a CloudSQL database.

I have already set up a Google CloudSQL database, run my Node api server on App Engine and successfully connected it to the database.

My next step is to upload my React frontend on another App Engine instance so it can make calls to my API server which will pass on the work to the database and back.

I have two questions:

1. How do I ensure that only my Node api server can access my cloudsql database? Both are in the same GCP project.
2. How do I ensure that only my React frontend app (hosted on App Engine) can use my api server or api routes?

I plan to implement Auth0 authentication on the frontend side to authenticate end users.

Comment: For 1, you have password on your cloudsql db, right ? For 2, you may implement some wort of security token so that only authorized app can access the APIs .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cloud SQL offers two levels of access control for an instance as mentioned in [this document](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/instance-access-control)

1 - Instance-Level Access

Instance-Level access authorizes access to your Cloud SQL instance from an application or client(running on App Engine Standard or externally) or from other Google Cloud services.

As you have stated that you have the Cloud SQL instance and App Engine in the same project so the access level is pre-configured otherwise if they are in different projects then you have to configure IAM. You have to only establish the connection by following [this document](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/connect-app-engine-standard) for App Engine Standard and [this document](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/connect-app-engine-flexible) for App Engine Flexible. So as the instance level access is preconfigured you don’t have to worry about it as it will only be accessible to the App Engine provided you should not have configured connection to Cloud SQL from any other resources.

2 - Database Access

After a connection to an instance has been established, the user or application must log in to the database instance with a user account. You can create and manage user accounts as part of managing your Cloud SQL instance.
You must set up the default user or root user when you create an instance, but you can also create more users to give you fine grained control over access to Cloud SQL instance. To know more about adding users you can refer to [this document](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/create-manage-users).

For the second question “How do I ensure that only my React frontend app (hosted on App Engine) can use my api server or api routes?” -

As you are using App Engine for both the React frontend and Node Express API server I assume you are using two services in App Engine in the same project. So to restrict access to the API server service in your App Engine you can use ingress controls as mentioned [here](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/go/application-security#ingress_controls). As you are using one project, I would suggest you to use `--egress=internal-only` so that it will only receive requests that are sent from VPC networks in the same project and all other requests are denied with a 403 error.

Comment: Wow, thank you very much for taking the time to answer my question comprehensively. I appreciate it very much. Great help for someone like me who is yet to learn more about backend development.